# Testing SOAP web service FROM SOAP UI and PHP

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I have been testing a web service with SOAP UI.
This what I put in SOAP UI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:b2b="http://www.dominio.com.emision.request">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <b2b:EmitirDocumentoRequest>
         <documento>Q0FCfDkwMTE4NzYxNXw5MDA0MDkyMjR8Rn</documento>
         <tipoDocumento>F</tipoDocumento>
         <empresa>FAC</empresa>
         <cuenta>FAC00111</cuenta>
         <usuario>USR_WS_FAC00111</usuario>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <serie>SETT</serie>
         <folio>5223</folio>
         <monto>1078232.00</monto>
         <fecha>2019-11-04</fecha>
         <hora>07:40:08</hora>
      </b2b:EmitirDocumentoRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

From SOAP UI works and the data is received correctly in those web services.

Now when I write this to PHP:

```
<?php

$factura = base64_encode(file_get_contents('FA002.txt'));
$client = new SoapClient("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/wsdl?configName=EmitirDocumento");
$datos = array(
    'documento' => $factura,
    'tipoDocumento' => 'F',
    'empresa' => 'FAC',
    'cuenta' => 'FAC00111',
    'usuario' => 'USR_WS_FAC00111',
    'serie' => 'SETT',
    'folio' => '5224',
    'monto' => 1078232.00,
    'fecha' => '2019-11-04',
    'hora' => '07:40:08'
);
$rs = $client->__soapCall('execute_EmitirDocumento', array($datos));
var_dump($rs);
```

Shows that is succesful, but the document is not sent to the web service, is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: I think maybe there's an extra array layer in the request. Try it with just `$datos` instead of `array($datos)`?

Comment: No, because that show this error:Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Receiver] Fault occurred in processing, detail provided. in C:\wamp64\www\proyecto\hc\php\facturacion\fac_mx\enviar.php on line

Comment: I tested it with nusoap and works, but nusoap show much errors and Deprecated: Methods

Comment: I found the mistake: not use  base64_encode().If your WSDL file containts a parameter with a base64Binary type, you should not use base64_encode() when passing along your soap vars. When doing the request, the SOAP library automatically base64 encodes your data, so otherwise you'll be encoding it twice.(https://www.php.net/manual/es/soapclient.soapclient.php)